# Different YAML configuration file for junit test using an Externalized configuration in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, junit5

I am following a [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-yaml-propertysource) on using external configuration files for Spring Boot. I got everything to work exactly as intended but I'm having issues overriding the default YAML config for my tests.

Could someone please point me in the right direction or advice if using '@PropertySource' is the best way to load config files into the project (There is a bunch of properties and I would like to keep the application.yaml as clean as possible)

**Project Structure:**

```
src: - main/resources/foo.yml <-- always loads this one
     - test/resources/foo.yml <-- never loads
```

**What I tried:**

```
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:foo.yml")
```

Doesn't load test/resoruces/foo.yml to the classpath

```
ActiveProfiles()
```

How I usually change config properties but in this case, it's not a profile so it doesn't work.

**Details**:

Spring boot: 2.2.7.RELEASE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@TestPropertySource(properties = { "spring.config.location=classpath:foo.yml" })
```